# Scroll down to element on page load only if the wrapper div has a certain class

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following structure:

[image]

I want the page to scroll to the `#form_city` element but only when `#wrapper` has the class `.results`

What's the simplest way to accomplish that?

Comment: What does your current code look like?

Comment: Do you want to do this on click, on page load, something else?  Also would be helpful to make a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. And it gives a smooth scroll.

```
if($('#wrapper').hasClass('results')){
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
     scrollTop: $("#form_city").offset().top
 }, 800);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
if ($("#wrapper").hasClass("results")) {
    $(window).scrollTop($("#form_city").prop('scrollHeight') + parseInt($(".post-text").css("height")))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery:

```
$('#wrapper').hasClass('results').animate({
                                 scrollTop: $("#form_city").offset().top}, 2000);
```